# Docker-compose volumes doesn't copy any files

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-volume

I'm in Fedora 23 and i'm using docker-compose to build two containers: app and db.
I want to use that docker as my dev env, but have to execute docker-compose build and up every time i change the code isn't nice. So i was searching and tried the "volumes" option but my code doesn't get copied to docker.

When i run docker-build, a "RUN ls" command doesn't list the "app" folder or any files of it.

**Obs**.: in the root folder I have: docker-compose.yml, .gitignore, app (folder), db (folder)

**Obs¹**.:  If I remove the volumes and working_dir options and instead I use a "COPY . /app" command inside the app/Dockerfile it works and my app is running, but I want it to sync my code.

Anyone know how to make it work?

My docker-compose file is:

```
version: '2'  
services:  
  app:
    build: ./app
    ports:
     - "3000:3000"
    depends_on:
     - db
    environment:
     - DATABASE_HOST=db
     - DATABASE_USER=myuser
     - DATABASE_PASSWORD=mypass
     - DATABASE_NAME=dbusuarios
     - PORT=3000
    volumes:
     - ./app:/app
    working_dir: /app
  db:
    build: ./db
    environment:
     - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=123
     - MYSQL_DATABASE=dbusuarios
     - MYSQL_USER=myuser
     - MYSQL_PASSWORD=mypass
```

Here you can see my app container Dockerfile:
https://gist.github.com/jradesenv/d3b5c09f2fcf3a41f392d665e4ca0fb9

Heres the output of the RUN ls command inside Dockerfile:

bin
boot
dev
etc
home
lib
lib64
media
mnt
opt
proc
root
run
sbin
srv
sys
tmp
usr
var

Comment: How are you running docker, is it local, vm, or remote? `echo $DOCKER_HOST`

Comment: echo $DOCKER_HOST outputs nothing, but i'm running docker local

Answer (score 3):

A volume is mounted in a container. The Dockerfile is used to create the image, and that image is used to make the container. What that means is a `RUN ls` inside your Dockerfile will show the filesystem before the volume is mounted. If you need these files to be part of the image for your build to complete, they shouldn't be in the volume and you'll need to copy them with the `COPY` command as you've described. If you simply want evidence that these files are mounted inside your running container, run a

```
docker exec $container_name ls -l /
```

Where `$container_name` will be something like `${folder_name}_app_1`, which you'll see in a `docker ps`.

Comment: Looking for a way to keep track of file changes from inside the container, this has helped me realize that it is only after COPY that the container starts keeping track of the changes

Answer (score 1):

Two things, have you tried `version: '3'` version two seems to be outdated. Also try putting the working_dir into the `Dockerfile` rather than the docker-compose. Maybe it's not supported in version 2?

This is a recent docker-compose I have used with volumes and workdirs in the respective Dockerfiles:

```
version: '3'
services:
  frontend:
    build:
      context: ./frontend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
    ports:
      - 3001:3001
    volumes:
      - ./frontend:/app
    networks:
      - frontend
  backend:
    build: .
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    networks:
      - frontend
      - backend
    depends_on:
      - "mongo"
  mongo:
    image: mongo
    volumes:
      - ./data/db:/data/db
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    networks:
      - backend
networks:
  frontend:
  backend:
```

Answer (score 0):

You can extend or override docker compose configuration. Please follow for more info: https://docs.docker.com/compose/extends/

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue in Windows!

```
volumes:
      - ./src/:/var/www/html
```

In windows `./src/` this syntax might not work in regular `command prompt`, **so use `powershell` instead** and then run `docker-compose up -d`.

it should work if it's a mounting issue.